# Emacs weird behaviour with key

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

I'm a Vim user, and I decided to give Emacs a try.

Now I get a weird problem with Emacs. I installed the Evil mode, which is awesome.

In my .emacs I have the follow setting:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-u" 'scroll-up-command)
```

This works well.

But what if I wanted to change it to spacebar or Return key?

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "<return>" 'scroll-up-command)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "SPC" 'scroll-up-command)
```

Nothing spectular will happen, the return/Enter key and spacebar are behaving their standard behaviour. I looked around for the right keys, and it seems they're the rights keys. For example,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<return>") 'save-buffer)
```

Works fine.

What am I doing wrong in Emacs/Evil with the Enter key?

Comment: Hey ! Hopefully you'll like those evil tips: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `(kbd "<return>")`, not `"<return>"`.  Likewise, `(kbd "SPC")`.
2. You probably want `(kbd "RET")`, not `(kbd "<return>")`.
3. Binding `C-u`, as you did at first, is a **bad** idea. You do not want to do that, ever. Just use `C-u` as it was intended, for command `universal-argument` -- see the Emacs manual, node `Arguments`.